# combine two conditions on different lines in one record in Awk

Tags: shell, awk, scripting, aix

In below `test.log` file I want to search only today's date with Message "Upload_Msg_testListeningFn"; if both the conditions match then redirect the output.

```
cat /tmp/test.log 
===========================================================================
system Version [45.2.18] (FATAL ERROR INFORMATION)
File: [test003.cxx]
Line: [240]

Date: [19-01-2018 21:09:40]
User ID: [SYSTEM]
Message : [batman error: Upload_Msg_testListeningFn]
Error Code : [TEST0000057]
Outside FGH
Session Id: 6768678898:00:F

=======================================
```

Output should be:

```
Date: [19-01-2018 21:09:40]
Message : [batman error: Upload_Msg_testListeningFn]
```

I used awk but somewhere I am missing something
i used the below command for finding lines after particular date.

```
awk '/^Date/{c=3} c&&c--' /tmp/test.log
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow, please post the sample Input_file correctly in only code tags as it is not clear as of now.

Comment: Please update your post with CODE TAGS, comments are not meant for it.

Comment: unable to add that details in required format ,  from File:  is  one line after that Line: is new line ...same till id:

Comment: See this link for code tags in SO https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Comment: date wise I have 8 ilne input file ,     1 line start with system Version ,  2 line start with   File: , 3rd line start with Line:  , 4th line start with Status: , 5th line Date:

Comment: Sorry to say NOT clear still, please update your post.

Comment: now it's okay...

Comment: I used awk '/^Date/{for(i=0; i<=5; i++) {getline; print}}'  /tmp/test.log also but how to combine two condition.

Comment: This is a very common question. If the duplicate I selected isn't clear enough, there are several others.

Comment: today=`date "+%d-%m-%Y"`
awk '/`$today`/{c=3} c&&c--' /tmp/test.log  ..... but how to $today  in this case.

Comment: Yeah, that's https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19075671/how-do-i-use-shell-variables-in-an-awk-script -- not adding that as a separate duplicate.

Comment: thanks ... I used awk '/'"$today"'/{c=4} c&&c--' filename > newfilename than grep the output  which I required and set if test -s . ........my work done .....but still I searching how to combine both the output. ...any way thank you .